# form search to url

Tags: php, forms

I have the following code:

```
<form action="search.php" method="get" name="searchprod" id="prodsearch">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td><input name="q" type="text" id="searchbox"  value="Search" onfocus="this.value=''; this.style.color='#333333';" /></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Search" class="searchButton" /></td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
</form>
```

When a user searches how can i make it so it looks like this "Dvd-player.html" instead of "search.php?q=dvd+player"

I have the .htaccess in place however not sure how to do it within the form.

Comment: Are you saying you want the search results page or the product page to be `dvd-player.html`? On an SEO tangent, I would encourage you not to index your search results pages as they will compete with your product page and possibly be seen as *duplicate content*. As such, the URL of your search results page is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Javascript to change the form action to `searchbox-value.html` in the onsubmit event of the form.

Comment: I am somewhat concerned ad doing a GET operation with a target of .html. Usually indicates that .html is a file to download and not an executable to respond to the GET